# I get error "This package requires php >=7.2.5 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement." when doing composer update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, hhvm

Everytime I run composer update I get this error regarding HHVM version:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=7.2.5 but your HHVM version does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v7.14.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.3.5) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v7.9.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.3.5) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v7.9.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.3.5) overridden by "config.platform.php" version (7.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - etc.
```

My composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.5",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.10"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
```

composer update --ignore-platform-reqs does work but I want to fix the error.

How do I get rid of HHVM on Windows 10? (and switch it to PHP)

Comment: How to get rid of HHVM depends on how you installed it. And installing PHP 7.3 is well documented - what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? And how is all this related to Composer ifself?

Comment: Try update your Composer - AFAIK HHVM is ignored since a year or two.

Comment: @rob006 it works, thanks!